# numpy import erro in anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, python-2.x

I installed anaconda 64 bit python 3 and i am working on python 2.
I  got ImportError: No module named numpy even though i updated all packages. I still got the same error tips please:

Comment: could add the `traceback` to the question?

Comment: Post the output of `conda list` in the environment you are using.

Comment: hey the output of environmet is root and ipykernel_py2